# Remover ficheiro de uma JList e do computador

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Tenho uma frame, com uma lista de valores onde são apresentados vários ficheiros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste momento estou a fazer a sentinela do botão delete (ultima parte codigo), em que o objetivo é apagar o ficheiro do disco, e da jlist.

```
    public void addContentFrame(){
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //lista de ficheiros - criada como instancia da classe
    frame.add(listaFicheiros, BorderLayout.WEST);

    File[] files = new File(diretoriaExecucao).listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(".rtf");        //so aceita ficheiros acabados em .rtf
        }
    });

    //      Meter valores aleatorios na lista       
    //      model.addElement("A");
    //      model.addElement("B");
    //      model.addElement("C");

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){          //como nao e array percorremos o tamanho por inteiro do array
        model.addElement(files[i].getName());
    }

    //caixa texto onde vai ser apresentado o conteudo do ficheiro c/ ScrollArea 
    JTextArea caixaTexto = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollArea = new JScrollPane(caixaTexto);
    frame.add(scrollArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    listaFicheiros.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                String valorSelecionado =  (String) listaFicheiros.getSelectedValue(); 

                //Abrir ficheiro selecionado e meter output numa JTextArea!!
                try {       
                    caixaTexto.setText("");                     //limpo sempre a CT sempre que inicio a leitura de um ficheiro
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(diretoriaExecucao + "/" + valorSelecionado));

                    while(br.ready()){
                        String linha = br.readLine();
                        caixaTexto.append(linha + "\n");        //imprime continuamente as linhas na caixa texto
                    }
                    br.close();                                 //Ficheiro tem de ser sempre fechado
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //botoes - parte inferior janela
    JPanel painelBotoes = new JPanel();

    painelBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    JButton new1 = new JButton("new");

    new1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String nomeFicheiroNovo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Qual o nome do novo ficheiro?");

            //Criar um ficheiro novo e escrever para dentro dele

            File ficheiroNovo = new File(diretoriaExecucao + "/" + nomeFicheiroNovo + ".rtf");   //dentro e a diretoria que queremos gravar ficheiro (em execucao)

            //escrever para o ficheiro
            try {
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(ficheiroNovo);            //ESCREVE
                printWriter.println("Escreveu ficheiro?");                          //O que queremos escrever no ficheiro.

                model.addElement(ficheiroNovo.getName());               //adicionar ficheiro à lista para aparecer frame

                printWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    JButton delete = new JButton("delete");

    //Passos: ver ficheiro selecionado, percorre lista, remove ficheiro disco e lista, atualizar lista de ficheiro(atualiza sozinha)
    delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String ficheiroSelecionado = (String) listaFicheiros.getSelectedValue();

            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                if(files[i].getName().equals(ficheiroSelecionado)){         
                    files[i].delete();
                    model.removeElement(ficheiroSelecionado);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Apesar de conseguir apagar o ficheiro e a sentinela fazer o objetivo dela, a consola ainda me dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este erro ocorre na linha:

```
model.removeElement(ficheiroSelecionado);
```

Comment: Testei seu código e não recebi a mensagem. Acho que pode ser que quando o `System.out.println()` tenta exibir o arquivo, ele já foi apagado.

Comment: @diegofm sim é isso mesmo, ele é apagado. Mas mesmo sem o sysout ele dá me o mesmo erro.

Comment: @diegofm ele dá erro no model.removeElement(ficheiroSelecionado). Acha que não devia tirar do modelo? Devia primeiro tirar do array de files? e só depois do modelo?

Comment: Pode apresentar um exemplo do seu código que seja **[mcve]**? Como disse, reproduzi apenas o trecho atual e funcionou normalmente sem mensagem nenhuma.

Comment: ele removeu o ficheiro da lista, mas diz que não existe o path

Comment: Como disse, eu reproduzi exatamente o código atual da pergunta e nenhum problema foi detectado. Só poderá ser avaliado se você fizer como eu sugeri no post anterior.

Comment: O código que está na pergunta é um código de criação de arquivos. Se o problema está no de deleção, o código está incorreto. Por isso o @diegofm não está encontrando nenhum erro.

Comment: esqueci-me de colocar a sentinela do delete, agora já esta @mutlei

Comment: Já tentou alterar a ordem das duas operações, de remover da tabela antes e remover o arquivo depois?

Comment: sim dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Eu acho que então talvez esteja sendo usada a operação errada no model. Tenta usar `removeRow(int rowId)`.

Comment: Como eu já disse em comentários anteriores, não há nenhum problema com o código, a não ser a ordem deleção(você primeiro deve deletar o objeto do model e depois deletar fisicamente), as alterações são feitas corretamente, aquela mensagem é devido a você tentar exibir algo que já foi deletado, pois o `System.ou.println` estava sendo chamado após o `file[i].delete()`.